# Is there a notable performance decrease when using SVG instead of PNG/JPG/GIF on a web page?

Tags: html, image, performance, vector, raster

Vector graphics like SVG opposed to raster graphics like PNG still look nice when scaling a web page. With the wide use of mobile devices this is a great advantage of vector graphics. But is there any performance decrease also?

Comment: That depends on how complicated they are...

Comment: As @MrLister said, It depends how complicated the page is. If you have one SVD file the you shouldn't notice any drop in page performance.

Also, most mobile devices don't really have resolutions that are higher that PC's laptops's etc, so you shouldn't really need to worry about degraded image quality.